# Pausing a thread from a function python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I am using threading in my python program. The question I have is how do I pause the thread/stop it from another function, and then again restart it.

The method I use for threading is as follows:

```
import threading

def motor():
  #I want to stop the checkID thread here
  x=1 # starts the motor 
  # I want to restart the checkID() thread as the motor function execution is now complete


def checkID():

  if (ID==matched):
     motor()
  else:
      print 'id not matched'


def main():
  checkIDthread = threading.Thread(target=checkID)
  checkIDthread.start()
main()
```

So, I would like the checID function to be running all the time. But, when I call the motor() function to start a motor, I want to pause the checkID() thread, and then again restart it at the end of the motor() function, once the motor function execution is complete.

Can anyone let me know on how to do this ?

Comment: Wait a second, you're now calling `motor` from `checkID`, that should mean that the function will not continue until `motor` exits. Problem solved?

Comment: @bereal 

no, checkid() will continue to run again, as it is called as a thread.

Comment: `motor` is called in the same thread, because it's called from `checkID`.

Comment: @bereal but I have a slightly longer version of this program, and I see that in the program checkid starts running again even while motor() is still running. I need to recheck once. thank you.

Comment: do you call `motor()` somewhere else in the main thread or in another one ? in this case you need a `threading.Lock` that you `acquire()` at the beginning of `motor()`, and `release()` at the end - you might use a with statement to do so.